# algorithm for generating a random numeric string, 10,000 chars in length?

Tags: algorithm, string, big-o

Can be in any language or even pseudocode. I was asked this in an interview question, and was curious what you guys can come up with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a trick question - the obvious answer of generating digits using a standard library routine is almost certainly flawed, if you want to generate every possible 10000 digit number with equal probability...

If an algorithmic random number generator maintains *n* bits of state, then clearly it can generate *at most* 2<sup>n</sup> possible different output sequences, because there are only 2<sup>n</sup> different initial configurations.

2<sup>33219</sup> < 10<sup>10000</sup> < 2<sup>33220</sup>, so if your algorithm uses less than 33220 bits of internal state, it *cannot possibly* generate some of the 10<sup>10000</sup> possible 10000-digit (decimal) numbers.

Typical standard library random number generators won't use anything like this much internal state.  Even the  [Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html) (the most frequently mentioned generator with a large state that I'm aware of) only keeps 624 32-bit words (= 19968 bits) of state.

Answer (score 1):

Just one of many ways. You can pass in any string of the alphabet of characters you want to use:

```
public class RandomUtils
{
    private static readonly Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

    public static string GenerateRandomDigitString(int length)
    {
        const string digits = "1234567890";

        return GenerateRandomString(length, digits);
    }

    public static string GenerateRandomAlphaString(int length)
    {
        const string alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        return GenerateRandomString(length, alpha);
    }


    public static string GenerateRandomString(int length, string alphabet)
    {
        int maxlen = alphabet.Length;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(alphabet[random.Next(0, maxlen)]);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without additional requirements, this will work:

```
StringBuilder randomStr = new StringBuilder(10000);
Random rnd = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i<10000;i++)
{
  char randomChar = rnd.AsChar();
  randomStr[i] = randomChar;
}
```

This will result in unprintable characters and other unpleasentness.  Using an ASCII encoder you can get letters, numbers and punctutaiton by sticking to the range 32 - 126.  Or creating a random number between 0 and 94 and adding 32.  Not sure which aspect they were looking for in the question.

BTW, No I did not know the visible range off the top of my head, I looked it up on wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a number in the range 0..9. Convert it to a digit. Stuff that into a string. Repeat 10000 times.

Comment: I think the op is asking for the algorithm to actually perform the generation of the random digits without just tossing it to a library to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I always like saying Computer Random Numbers are always only pseudo-random. Anyway, your favourite language will invariably have a random library. Next what is a numeric string ? 0-9 valued for each character ? Well let's start with that assumption. So we can generate bytes between to Ascii codes of 0-9 with offset (48) and (int) random*10 (since random generators typically return floats). Then place these all in a char buffer 10000 long and convert to string.

Answer (score 0):

Return a string containing 10,000 `1`s -- that's just as random as any other digit string of the same length.

Comment: +1 for a real answer to a hypothetically unspecified question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a list of seed digits:

```
seeds = [4,9,3,1,2,5,5,4,4,8,4,3] # This should be relatively large
```

Then, use a counter to keep track of which digit was last used. This would be system-wide and shouldn't reset with the system:

```
def next_digit():
    counter = 0
    while True:
        yield counter
        counter += 1
pos_it = next_digit()
rand_it = next_digit()
```

Next, use an algorithm that uses modulus to determine the "next number":

```
def random_digit():
    position = pos_it.next() % len(seeds)
    digit = seeds[position] * rand_it.next()
    return digit % 10
```

Last, generate 10,000 of those digits.

```
output = ""
for i in range(10000):
    output = "%s%s" % (output, random_digit())
```

I believe that an ideal answer would use more prime numbers, but this should be pretty sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think the real question was to determine what the interviewer actually wanted. For example, random in what sense? Uncompressable? Random over multiple runs of the same algorithm? Etc.