# generating random printable ascii characters in c

Tags: c, ascii, random

i'm trying to write a program for testing purposes that generates a sequence of pseudo-random printable ASCII characters, where you put in the command line how many characters you want.  right now it's not working so well; the sequence is almost always majority ?s, and it doesn't always print the number of characters i tell it to print.  here's my code; what's wrong with it?  i use the time as a seed for the random function.

note: it's not worth it to me to use any algorithm more complicated than one using srand() and rand().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int c;
   int i;
   int limit;

   sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &limit);
   srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

   for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
      c = rand();
      if (c != 9 && c != 10 && c <= 32 && c >= 127) {
         i--;
      }
      else {
         putchar(c);
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

thanks!

Comment: although this answer is in C#, it should be relatively easy to convert to C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221001/algorithm-for-generating-a-random-numeric-string-10-000-chars-in-length/4221015#4221015

Comment: Why did you decide that 9 and 10 fall under "printable"?

Comment: Probably he meant `'\n'`

Comment: Try printing the numeric values of c and you'll see where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fixing this line:

```
  if (c != 9 && c != 10 && c <= 32 && c >= 127) {
```

should be:

```
  if (c != 9 && c != 10 && (c < 32 || c >= 127)) {
```

But this would probably be better:

```
  if (!isprint(c)) {
```

Comment: Really, rand() gives values in much wider range than 0..255 the typical behavior of this change will be printing nothing.

Comment: @horsh the code as written in the question keeps choosing random numbers until it finds something to print, so it won't print nothing, though it will waste a lot of time throwing out values it doesn't like in between printing stuff.

Comment: `rand() / (RAND_MAX/128)` might give better randomness.